# "issuerUserId" in custom policy in Azure AdB2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am working on AdB2C custom policy. I have added some fields required for Custom policy in B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase.xml file and I am continuously getting this error.

[image]

Please let me know what I am missing and what is "issuerUserId"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the ClaimType in the ClaimsSchema in your TrustFrameworkBase.xml

```
<BuildingBlocks>
<ClaimsSchema>
...
  <ClaimType Id="issuerUserId">
    <DisplayName>Issuer User Id</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
  </ClaimType>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

issuerUserId is already in the base policy if you are using the "LocalAndSocial" starter pack.

It's used in the Facebook technical provider.

Have you perhaps deleted that?